# Paste clipboard content into a variable in bash using xclip

Tags: bash, clipboard, xclip

I know this command will paste the clipboard contents into a file:

```
xclip -out -selection clipboard >> file.txt
```

If I want to paste clipboard content into a variable like a string what do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To assign the output of a command to a variable, you can use command substitution:

```
myvar=$( command )
echo "$myvar"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can output by `echo` your clipboard contents using `xclip`:

```
clipboard_content=`xclip -o -selection clipboard`
echo "$clipboard_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can output echo your clipboard by xsel also:

```
myvar=$( xsel -ob )
echo "$myvar"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using

```
#!/bin/bash
# collect contents of clipboard
ln=$(xsel -ob)
#
# manipulate contents of the variable ln
#
# "post result back to clipboard, -n without newline at end
echo -n $ln | xclip -sel c
```

xsel and xclip were installed using Synaptic