# How to get value from Clipboard in bash

Tags: linux, bash, macos, clipboard

like in subject. I'm curious how to get value in bash script from Clipboard.

I would like to write sh script which after execution will take value from Clipboard (Ctrl+c), but I haven't found how to get this value in the script.

Any idea folks, thanks :)

Comment: [Pipe to/from the clipboard in Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/749544/608639), [Paste clipboard content into a variable in bash using xclip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23046580/608639), [Copy a string to clipboard from Mac OS command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39692617/608639), [Copy pure text from clipboard using AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15190868/608639), [shell script output to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4023703/608639), [Is there an Environment Variable that contains the clipboard contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1064762/608639), etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Mac OS, [`pbcopy`/`pbpaste`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html):

```
echo "Set the clipboard" | pbcopy

clipboard="$(pbpaste)"
```

On Linux with X11, [`xclip`](https://github.com/astrand/xclip).

```
echo "Set the clipboard" | xclip

clipboard="$(xclip -o)"
```